# Python for Maya - Invalid arguments for flag 'c'. Expected string or function, got NoneType

Tags: python, maya

Trying to convert a simple tool that selects all hard edges of a mesh in Maya. Basically I'm trying to convert this Mel script to Python and give it a UI just for a bit of practise with Python scripting for Maya. I'm running into an issue where I'm feeding a function into a UI button but when I run the code it returns:

> Error: TypeError: file  line 18: Invalid arguments for flag 'c'.  Expected string or function, got NoneType #

Here's the code:

```
import pymel.core as pm

def createWindow():
    
    title = 'Hard Edge Selection'
    
    if cmds.window(title, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(title, window=True)
    else:
            cmds.window(t = title)
            cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=2)
            lowAngle = cmds.intSliderGrp( field=True, label='Low Angle', minValue=0, maxValue=30, value=30 )
            highAngle = cmds.intSliderGrp( field=True, label='High Angle', minValue=90, maxValue=150, value=150 )
            lowAngleSel = cmds.intSliderGrp( lowAngle, q=True, value=True)
            highAngleSel = cmds.intSliderGrp( highAngle, q=True, value=True)
            #_findEdges = findEdges("{0},{1}").format(lowAngleSel, highAngleSel)
            cmds.button(l='Find Edges', c=findEdges(lowAngleSel, highAngleSel))
            cmds.showWindow()
            cmds.selectMode(o=True)

def findEdges(x, y):
    currentSelection = cmds.ls(sl=True)
    pm.mel.doMenuComponentSelectionExt(currentSelection[0], "edge", 0)
    #edgecount = pm.polyEvaluate(currentSelection[0], e=1)
    #pm.select(currentSelection[0] + ".e [0:" + str((edgecount[0] - 1)) + "]")

    #Constrain that selection to only edges of a certain Angle
    pm.polySelectConstraint(a=True, ab=(x, y), m=3, t=0x8000)
    #Remove the selection constraint so everything back to normal
    pm.polySelectConstraint(m=0)
    print ("Hard edges between " + str(x) + " and " + str(y) + " degrees have been selected")

createWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this line:

```py
cmds.button(l='Find Edges', c=findEdges(lowAngleSel, highAngleSel))
```

`findEdges(...)` returns `None`, which is then attempted to bind to the command-callback for your button.

What you need to be doing is binding your callback to the actual function, like this:

```py
cmds.button(l='Find Edges', c=findEdges)
```

However, that presents the issue of how to send your function parameters. Personally, I would suggest using a class for this and storing your slider groups on the class instance, but if you want to proceed down your current path you should look at `lambda` and `partial` implementations.

PS: I believe the button callback sends the button's name as an argument to the callback function, which you would need to capture (and probably ignore):

```py
cmds.button(l='Find Edges', c=lambda x: findEdges(lowAngleSel, highAngleSel))
```

PPS: I'm not entirely sure about the scope of the `lambda` arguments above, it may be that they come up as undefined at callback time. In which case, you could fall back to `partial` (which acts as a factory, instead of anonymous method).

Some more information on Maya button callbacks: https://riptutorial.com/maya/example/25096/callback-functions